# Local variable 'q' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Whenever I use the minimax function, I get that error.
RQ: If player(board) == X, k will always be superior to -2
If player(board) == O, k will always be inferior to 2

```
def minimax(board):
"""
Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
"""
if terminal(board):
    return None

if player(board) == X:
    p=-2
    for a in actions(board):
        k=Min_Value(result(board,a))
        if p < k:
            p = k
            q = a

elif player(board) == O:
    p = 2
    for a in actions(board):
        k = Max_Value(result(board, a))
        if p > k:
            p = k
            q = a
return (q)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, the two `elif` functions do not return anything. So if both `player(board) == X` and `player(board) == 0` are false, then the variable `q` is not yet set and thus the return statement will throw that error. Try setting `q=None` at the beginning of the function, this will solve the error but you probably should look at the logic you are applying as it doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: The player(board) function will always return either X or O. I just changed the second elif to else, so q will always have a value. Unfortunately, I still get the same error message..

Comment: Is it possible that `p` is always < or > `k`? That is where the actual assignment happens. Fact is, your function complains that you are trying to return a variable that hasn't been initiated yet, so either Python is incorrect or your logic is ;)

Comment: Have you tried setting debug points on the lines `q = a` and `return q`? That way you can see if they are actually executed prior to the `return q` line. Without any more context there is little we can do to help.

Comment: k is always limited to 3 values : it can be either 1,0, or -1. For the first condition (if p<k), p was initialized to -2. So the if will always work at least once, thus affecting a value to q. Same logic for the second if statement (if p>k) (p was initialized to 2).

Comment: And sorry but I'm new to Python and I have no idea how to set a debug point, +I didn't find any tutorial on the internet. Btw, you asked for more context, should I send the entire program here? Do you need all the functions + the main (the runner), or will the functions be enough?(I have no problem sharing them I just didn't want to bother you with manyyy functions and lines of codes, thought it was useless to share everything)

Comment: What IDE do you use (your programing tool in which you write Python code, like Visual Studio Code or PyCharm)? You usually debug your code via your IDE, so it's really dependant on that. Try googling 'how to debug Python in x' where x is your IDE. It's an invaluable tool when you develop any kind of code.

Comment: Thank you so much for making me start using the debugger, it's a life savior! And adding the q=none solved the problem! Also, as you said, the player(board) function had a little logic problem that I solved, and now everything is working just fine even without adding the q=None. Thanks!